# while loop strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have a while loop like ths:

```
var running_time = 0;
var start_time = new Date();
while( cars.length > 0 )
{
    this.update(null, running_time)
    for(var i in cars )
    {
        var car = cars[i];
        car.delay = 0;
        car.update(start_time, this)
    } 

    for( var i in cars_to_remove )
    {
        var index = cars.indexOf(cars_to_remove[i]);
        if( index > -1 )
        {
            cars.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    cars_to_remove.splice(0, cars_to_remove.length);
    running_time++;
}
var end_time = new Date();
```

What I'm doing here is, that I'm simulating an animation of cars movement and traffic lights . Loop runs until all cars reached destination. When car reached destination is marked to be removed from cars array (see second loop).

When I debug this while loop with breakpoint in while loop, is running_time variable usually around 90, but when I don't have a breakpoint in while loop, and set breakpoint on last line in example above, the value of running_time variable is more thousands (around 12000).

Where's the catch?

Answer (score 0):

You are not pushing the finished cars to `cars_to_remove` array. (Or is it just missing from the displayed code ?)

Are you using `setTimeout`/`setInterval` in the functions for updating the animation ? 
The iterations taken when you debug and wait on break-points will be less than normal execution, if there is a time out is involved in updating the car position.

Usually this has to be done in either of the following ways.

*Method1* (pseudo code)

```
while(condition){
    calculatePosition();
    updatePosition();
}

function updatePosition(){
    if(condition){
       marktoRemove();
    }else{
       setTimeout(function(){
           updateDisplay();
       }, delay);
       delay += 100; // for e.g.
    }
}
```

*Method2* (pseudo code) - No While Loop

```
setTimeout(function(){

    calculatePosition();

    if(condition){
       marktoRemove();
    }else{
       updateDisplay();
    }     

}, delay);
```

Second method is recommended.